# Reading the next line in the file and keeping counts separate

Tags: perl, sequence, counting

Another question for everyone. To reiterate I am very new to the Perl process and I apologize in advance for making silly mistakes

I am trying to calculate the GC content of different lengths of DNA sequence. The file is in this format:

```
>gene 1
DNA sequence of specific gene
>gene 2
DNA sequence of specific gene
...etc...
```

This is a small piece of the file

```
  >env
  ATGCTTCTCATCTCAAACCCGCGCCACCTGGGGCACCCGATGAGTCCTGGGAA
```

I have established the counter and to read each line of DNA sequence but at the moment it is do a running summation of the total across all lines. I want it to read each sequence, print the content after the sequence read then move onto the next one. Having individual base counts for each line.

This is what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


#necessary code to open and read a new file and create a new one.
use strict;
my $infile = "Lab1_seq.fasta";
open INFILE, $infile or die "$infile: $!";
my $outfile = "Lab1_seq_output.txt";            
open OUTFILE, ">$outfile" or die "Cannot open $outfile: $!";

#establishing the intial counts for each base
my $G = 0;
my $C = 0;
my $A = 0;
my $T = 0;

 #initial loop created to read through each line 
 while ( my $line = <INFILE> ) {
chomp $line;


# reads file until the ">" character is encounterd and prints the line
if ($line =~ /^>/){
    print OUTFILE "Gene: $line\n";

}
# otherwise count the content of the next line. 
# my percent counts seem to be incorrect due to my Total length counts skewing the following line. I am currently unsure how to fix that
elsif ($line =~ /^[A-Z]/){
    my @array = split //, $line;
    my $array= (@array);
 # reset the counts of each variable
    $G = (); 
    $C = ();
    $A = ();
    $T = ();
    foreach $array (@array){ 
 #if statements asses which base is present and makes a running total of the bases.     
    if ($array eq 'G'){
        ++$G;   
    }        
    elsif ( $array eq 'C' ) {
    ++$C; }
    elsif ( $array eq 'A' ) {
    ++$A; }
    elsif ( $array eq 'T' ) {
    ++$T; }

  } 
# all is printed to the outfile
    print OUTFILE "G:$G\n";
    print OUTFILE "C:$C\n";
    print OUTFILE "A:$A\n";
    print OUTFILE "T:$T\n";
    print OUTFILE "Total length:_", ($A+=$C+=$G+=$T), "_base pairs\n";
    print OUTFILE "GC content is(percent):_", (($G+=$C)/($A+=$C+=$G+=$T)*100),"_%\n";


}

}
#close the outfile and the infile
close OUTFILE; 
close INFILE;
```

Again I feel like I am on the right path, I am just missing some basic foundations. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The final problem is in the final counts printed out. My percent values are wrong and give me the wrong value. I feel like the total is being calculated then that new value is incorporated into the total.

Comment: So I worked through it and altered my own original code in an attempt to get it working. It now looks like the following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reset the counters when a new gene is found. Also, I'd use hashes for the counting:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my %counts;
while (<>) {
  if (/^>/) {
    # print counts for the prev gene if there are counts:
    print_counts(\%counts) if keys %counts;
    %counts = (); # reset the counts
    print $_;     # print the Fasta header
  } else {
    chomp;
    $counts{$_}++ for split //;
  }
}
print_counts(\%counts) if keys %counts;  # print counts for last gene

sub print_counts {
  my ($counts) = @_;
  print "$_:=", ($counts->{$_} || 0), "\n" for qw/A C G T/;
}
```

Usage: `$ perl count-bases.pl input.fasta`.

Example output:

```
> gene 1
A:=3
C:=1
G:=5
T:=5
> gene 2
A:=1
C:=5
G:=0
T:=13
```

#### Style comments:

When `open`ing a file, always use lexical filehandles (normal variables). Also, you should do a three-arg open. I'd also recommend the `autodie` pragma for automatic error handling (since perl v5.10.1).

```
use autodie;
open my $in,  "<", $infile;
open my $out, ">", $outfile;
```

Note that I don't open files in my above script because I use the special `ARGV` filehandle for input, and print to `STDOUT`. The output can be redirected on the shell, like

```
$ perl count-bases.pl input.fasta >counts.txt
```

Declaring scalar variables with their values in parens like `my $G = (0)` is weird, but works fine. I think this is more confusing than helpful. → `my $G = 0`.

Your intendation is a bit weird. It is very unusual and visually confusing to put closing braces on the same line with another statement like

```
...
elsif ( $array eq 'C' ) {
    ++$C; }
```

I prefer cuddling elsif:

```
   ...
} elsif ($base eq 'C') {
    $C++;
}
```

This statement `my $array= (@array);` puts the length of the array into `$array`. What for? Tip: You can declare variables right inside foreach-loops, like `for my $base (@array) { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my errors. I am hoping I can prevent bad habits from forming. I can see how cuddling elsif makes a lot more sense visually.

Comment: I hate to ask another really dumb question but the first line of my .fasta file is ">env". How do I declare this as my gene 1? Do I create each gene as a key of the associative array?

Comment: @ZombieJohn Associative arrays are called a *hash* in Perl. If I understood the question correctly, It isn't neccessary to add any declarations; any line starting with `>` should be recognized as a gene by my script.

Comment: I don't seem to get any output from the script.

Comment: @ZombieJohn weird, it works for me. What OS are you using? Could you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18303296/edit) to include the first few lines from your input file?

Comment: @amom I am using windows and I have just included some of the file in there starting at line 1.

Comment: @ZombieJohn please be aware that the `$` is the prompt on my shell. It is not part of a command to be typed. The file you've shown works for me when the `>env` is the first thing on the line. If it may be preceded by spaces, use the regex `/^\s*>/` instead of `/^>/` for the `if`.

Comment: @amom so I altered my own ugly script with your tips and I got my one almost working. The only problem is now calculating the final total as described in my edit.

Comment: @ZombieJohn The percentages are wrong because you use the `+=` operator where you want simple addition with `+`.

Comment: @amom thanks for all the help mate. It really helps having someone point out these smaller basic errors.

Answer (score 1):

Several things: 
1. use hash instead of declaring each element.
2. assignment such as `$G = (0);` is indeed working, but it is not the right way to assign scalar. What you did is declaring an array, which in scalar context `$G =` is returning the first array item. The correct way is `$G = 0`.

```
my %seen;
$seen{/^([A-Z])/}++ for (grep {/^\>/} <INFILE>);

foreach $gene (keys %seen) {
    print "$gene: $seen{$gene}\n";
}
```

Comment: Should be created under my while loop?

Comment: No, this is the full program. just declare the file handlers before the code you are good to go.